# Accessing the Android media stream for audio visualization

Tags: java, android, audio

Basically, I want to make an audio visualizer.  I know it's possible, because my phone came with a few live wallpapers that do it.  The problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to do this with the Android API.

My app would pick up the currently playing media stream and then depending upon the volume that is playing at that time, it would display more or less bars on the screen.

How can I do this?  It looks like I could do something like this using the microphone, but I want to be able to do it for music, podcasts, etc.

Comment: There could be serious privacy issues for one app acquiring the audio from another app (e.g., VOIP).

Comment: See my answer farther down, 2.3 solves this in a secure way, via a low-resolution audio-sniffing visualizer api.

snoop() will not work on 2.3 devices, function not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [MusicVisualization wallpaper source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/MusicVisualization/) is available at the [AOSP](http://source.android.com/). It basically seems to involve calling [`MediaPlayer.snoop()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/froyo-release/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java), an undocumented method added in Eclair.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't have time to test this before the bounty expires, but this seems to be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, please post a link to your results here!

Answer (score 7):

It looks like in 2.3 things have changed here, there is permissions now

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
```

And there is a AudioCapture helper class in the aosp to help the live wallpapers do it properly.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/wallpapers/MusicVisualization/+/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/musicvis/AudioCapture.java

**Edit:**

One of the imports in the AOSP doesn't match the public api.
`import android.media.audiofx.Visualizer;`

it is
`import android.media.Visualizer;`

if it gives a headache make sure to switch. This is all 2.3 api, it apparently returns a low-resolution audio stream for viz, but not good enough for recording.

Comment: For 2.3+, this is the way to go. See here for an example implementation: https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer

Answer (score 3):

Basically what roskit said except with a minor return value modification from

```
return 0;
```

to

```
return Integer.parseInt( (m.invoke(c, outData, kind)).toString() );
```

In other words:

```
public static int snoop(short [] outData, int kind){    
              try {
                  Class c = MediaPlayer.class;
                  Method m = c.getMethod("snoop", outData.getClass(), Integer.TYPE);
                  m.setAccessible(true);
                  return Integer.parseInt( (m.invoke(c, outData, kind)).toString() ); 
              } catch (Exception e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
               return 1;
           }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it from my application:

```
protected short [] mAudioData = new short[1024];
```

Then in the loop:

```
int res = snoop(mAudioData, 0);
```

And here is the function itself:

```
public static int snoop(short [] outData, int kind){    
    try {
        Class c = MediaPlayer.class;
        Method m = c.getMethod("snoop", outData.getClass(), Integer.TYPE);
        m.setAccessible(true);
        m.invoke(c, outData, kind);
        return 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly faster `snoop()` would be to call `Class.getMethod()` once, and then to use a custom `parseInt()` instead of `Integer.parseInt()`...

```
private static Method mSnoop;

//..(http://nadeausoftware.com/node/97)..
private static int customParseInt( final String s )
{
    // Check for a sign.
    int num  = 0;
    int sign = -1;
    final int len  = s.length( );
    final char ch  = s.charAt( 0 );
    if ( ch == '-' )
        sign = 1;
    else
        num = '0' - ch;

    // Build the number.
    int i = 1;
    while ( i < len )
        num = num*10 + '0' - s.charAt( i++ );

    return sign * num;
} 

private static int snoop(short [] outData, int kind)
{    
    if ( mSnoop != null )
    {
        try
        {
            return customParseInt( (mSnoop.invoke( MediaPlayer.class , outData, kind)).toString() );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Log.e( TAG, "Failed to MediaPlayer.snoop()!", e );
            return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        try {
            Class c = MediaPlayer.class;
            Method m = c.getMethod("snoop", outData.getClass(), Integer.TYPE);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            mSnoop = m;
            return customParseInt( (m.invoke(c, outData, kind)).toString() ); 
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e( TAG, "Failed to MediaPlayer.snoop()!", e );
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://code.google.com/p/moonblink/wiki/Tricorder for an example.

Comment: The tricorder app uses the microphone for audio visualization.  I want to be able to pull the information from the raw stream so it would work even if you're wearing headphones, and it wouldn't be affected by external noises.

Comment: The link is broken.