# Developing Android outside of the SDK

Tags: java, android

It seems as if every Android application I really want to make is impossible to make with the current SDK.  It doesn't give me access to certain things I would like to work with.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571814/accessing-the-android-media-stream-for-audio-visualization) is an example of one of these things.

I know it is possible since I've seen apps in the market that do things that the SDK cannot do.  My basic question is can someone point me in the direction of how to create such an application.  I've searched around, but all of the links I've found are for developing with the SDK.  A simple link to a tutorial that can show me how to access Android elements that aren't available through the SDK would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that anything you use outside of the SDK is going to be undocumented and rely on private APIs, which might change between OS versions and between handset OEMs. And might be a reason for your application to be rejected from the App Market.

Comment: @Franci Penov: Actually, an app that uses private APIs and the like won't get rejected from the Android Market.

Comment: It won't be rejected but will most probably break on some devices or in a future version of Android and make users unhappy.

Comment: @CommonsWare - that is an interesting policy. I'll bet you it'll change at some point, though.

Comment: @Franci Penov: Most of the apps I want to build are for my own personal use, but I would probably try to get a version of them on the market if they worked well enough.  If the Android SDK ever added the functionality I use, I would simply modify the app to use the SDK api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not find a tutorial on it because the NDK is in flux..

What I have found is ..

1. One of the Eclipse CDT has blog posts on how to setup NDK projects in Eclipse.
2. The people who know Android Embedded C and frameworks are usually on certain IRc channel.
3. Plenty of code documentation..
4. Google search for android jni wrapper blog posts.

But keep this in mind several areas require state management as hey interact with hardware buffers in a certain way..ie audio..video..etc.

Comment: This is probably the best answer I'll get for this question.  You've definitely given me a few paths to go down, and that's mainly what I was looking for.  Thanks!