# Can I access the audio output of an Android device in order to modify it before the user hears it?

Tags: android, audio, audio-streaming

The scenario is that any app or the system creates an audio output which is then routed to the speaker of the Android device. Now, I would like to get access to this audio stream before it reaches the user (of course, with the permission of said user). Is there a way to do this?

I checked out a previous topic on this as well but was wondering if things have changed in the past year with Android: 
[How can I intercept the audio stream on an android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3202939/how-can-i-intercept-the-audio-stream-on-an-android-device)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

No.  You can not do this.

It would be a pretty major security loop hole, would allow your app to directly impact the operation of other apps in non lifecycle appropriate ways, and directly negate multiple contracts the Android system depends on for orderly operation.